# How to import data window sensor data into python to be fed to a CNN for HAR

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, har

I am currently working on a project to classify different upper body exercises using 2 gyroscopes and 1 accelerometer (9 channels of data). My approach is to use a sliding window approach for 6 exercises, and feed the windows to the CNN. The data is collected at 25Hz, and I created windows of 64 samples (2.56 seconds, with 50% overlap -> 32 samples) 9 channels. The dimensions of the windows are thereby 9x64 (Rows correspond to the different sensors and the columns to the readings), the reason for this is to be able to perform the convolution operations in the time domain (horizontal axis). With that being said I have created a small database with 60 windows per exercise, for a total of 360 windows. The data set contains 2 folders (Train, Test), where each of these two folders has 6 folders within (Each corresponding to the different exercises). In each exercise folder I have 48 windows for the Training samples and 12 windows for the testing samples. Each window is saved as a CSV file, with the dimensions of 9x64. My question is, what is the best solution to import the data using keras into the CNN. I have done a similar project using JPEG images, using the ImageDataGenerator prepossessing class from keras. For this project I had two folders (Test, Train) and each folder contain a folder for Cat and Dog pictures. My question is if there's a similar approach to import the data using CSV files :)